# Using data from geoportal.vizugy.hu

Tags: qgis, shapefile, mapping, create

I am new at GIS software. How can I create a file type from the following web map that can be used in ArcGIS, e.g.: shapefile
Link: https://geoportal.vizugy.hu/elontes/

Comment: REST service is https://geoportal.vizugy.hu/arcgis/rest/services/AKK_3D/Arteri_oblozetek/MapServer/ can be used in ArcGIS or QGIS.

Answer (score 1):

You asked about ArcGIS, but you tagged with QGIS. This answer is for QGIS, however, it should work in a similar was for ArcGIS as well.

To get a basemap, you can use XYZ-tiles, select the one you want to drag-and-drop it to the layer panel. The basemap on the linked site seems to be the Esri Topo World layer.

If you run QGIS 3+ for the first time, there is "only" OpenStreetMap available. See here [how to add additional XYZ-tiles](https://twitter.com/klaskarlsson/status/972757121933733889?).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can open the map layers in ArcGIS or QGIS using the following URLs

ArcGIS Feature Service Layer

- https://geoportal.vizugy.hu/arcgis/rest/services/AKK_3D/Arteri_oblozetek/MapServer

ArcGIS Map Service Layer

- https://geoportal.vizugy.hu/arcgis/rest/services/AKK_3D/VARGEO_public_AKK/MapServer
- https://geoportal.vizugy.hu/arcgis/rest/services/AKK_3D/Elontes_public/MapServer
- https://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer

The last URL, for World_Topo_Map, can be consumed with various ways but I choose to consume it as WMTS e.g https://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml